# Multiplication table using recursion without loops

Tags: c, recursion, multiplication

I've received an assignment to write a recursive function that receives two integersd from the user: `x` and `y` and  prints out the multiplication table up to the number `x*y`.
the prototyping of the function must be exactly like: `void mult_table (int x, int base, int y)` 
(`base` gets `1` upon the first time that the function is called).
for example, if `x=4` and `y=5`, the output will be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
```

note that no loop can be used inside the function, but additional recursive functions can be used if needed.

my problems are:
 1. how to iterate base correctly in lines 2 and greater, because in line 1 simple ++ works, but for the second line i already need 
 2. that I can't think about a stopping case for the function, because each time that I'm about to print a new line the `x` and `y` values are changed.
I would be very grateful for any help, even suggestions of other ways to try and do it.

```
void mult_table (int x, int base, int y)
{
    int temp; //temp variable to hold x vlaue
    if (base <= y) //as long as base is less or equal to y, a number of line will be printed
    {
        printf(" %d", base); //using base with +1 incrementation
        mult_table(x, base+1, y);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n"); //start of a new line
        temp = x; //value of x is saved because it will be changed but it is still needed
        x= x+x*(1/(base-temp-1)); //new x value x+(x*1/original base of line) to reach the next x value
        y = y+y*(1/(base-temp-1)); //new y value y+(y*1/original base of line) to reach the next x value
        base = base - temp; //base is incrimented by 1 using this calcualtion
        mult_table(x, base, y); //recursdive call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

at each call increase `base` by one. Then you have to decompose `base` into `f1` and `f2` such that `f1 * f2` is what you need to print at step `base`. I could give you the formula, but since this is an assignment I choose just to give you a hint: write in a table the values of base and the expected values of `f1` and `f2` and then you have to find 2 formulas to compute `f1` and `f2` based on `base` and `y`.

E.g. (for x=4 and y=5):

```
base  f1  f1
  1    1   1
  2    1   2
    ..
  4    1   5
  5    2   1
  6    2   2
    ..
and so on
```

Hints:

- notice that `f2` kind of loops around a range. Think that the mathematical `mod` (`%` in c) does something like that.
- notice that `f1` grows by one each `k` iterations. Think that `/` does something like that.

Comment: @Medvednic let me know if you figure it out

Comment: np, will probably be tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Write two recursive functions, one to recurse over the value of `x` and other to recurse over the values of `y`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mult_table_y(int x, int y)
{
   if ( y != 1 )
   {
      mult_table_y(x, y-1);
   }
   printf("%d ", x*y);
}

void mult_table(int x, int y)
{
   if ( x != 1 )
   {
      mult_table(x-1, y);
   }
   mult_table_y(x, y);
   printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
   mult_table(5, 5);
}
```

Comment: Is the complexity for this equal to O(n)?

Comment: Since there are two variables, I don't think you can describe its complexity using `O(n)`. If `x  = m` and `y = n`, this require `m x n` operations. Maybe, you would describe its complexity as `O(m x n)`.